# Connecting to Private GKE cluster from local Machine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, vpn, openvpn, gke-networking

We have a private GKE cluster created for a development purpose., And we have a requirement where-in we should be able to connect to this private GKE cluster from our local machines when connected with a VPN.,

1. We have setup a OpenVPN CE on a VM instance within the same GCP project where we have this GKE cluster created.
2. I have enabled the firewall rule 10.8.0.0/24 which is the default Virtual tunnel network for the OpenVPN CE.
3. Also i have added the 10.8.0.0 ip to the authorized Network list of the private GKE cluster.

I installed the OpenVPN GUI on my local machine and try to run Kubectl commands but it fails with the below error

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp x.x.x.x:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Comment: Does your cluster have the public endpoint for the control plane enabled or disabled?

Comment: Nope The cluster has private end point and the control plan global access is disabled. @GariSingh

Comment: Then you will need to follow https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#cp-on-prem-routing with the key being  you need to update the peering connection to export routes from your VPC.

Comment: The easiest path is to use the "Public endpoint access enabled, authorized networks enabled" option listed at https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept#overview as you don't need a VPN and access to the control plane is restricted to your on-prem network(s).

Comment: No luck @WytrzymałyWiktor., You share with me the steps if you have any